# How can I get cached data outside using apollo-server-cache?

Tags: node.js, caching, graphql, apollo-server

The `apollo-server-cache` and `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache` works fine in the system of `apollo-server` and GraphQL.

Now, I want to get the cached data outside, but still using `apollo-server-cache`. The "outside" means get the cached data in a REST API or a pubsub event handler. Code here:

`server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import responseCachePlugin from 'apollo-server-plugin-response-cache';
import { typeDefs } from './typeDefs';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import { context } from './context';
import http from 'http';
import { cache } from './cache';

async function createServer(): Promise<http.Server> {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
  const app = express();
  const graphqlPath = '/graphql';
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context,
    plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
    cacheControl: {
      defaultMaxAge: 30,
    },
    cache,
  });

  app.get('/test-cache', (req, res) => {
    const val = cache.get('?');
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: graphqlPath });

  return app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Apollo server is listening on http://localhost:${port}${graphqlPath}`);
  });
}

export { createServer };
```

`cache.ts`:

```js
import { RedisCache } from 'apollo-server-cache-redis';

const cache = new RedisCache({
  port: Number.parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT || '6379', 10),
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  family: 4,
  db: process.env.REDIS_DB || 0,
});

export { cache };
```

As you can see, I want to get the cached data in the `/test-cache` REST API. The problem is I don't know the cache key. The cache key is calculated based on graphql request, [source code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-server-plugin-response-cache/src/ApolloServerPluginResponseCache.ts#L192).  Is this possible? How should I use the cached data outside `apollo-server` and `GraphQL`?